# ImportError: No module named easydict

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to run the demo of `py-faster-rcnn` based on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/xinleipan/py-faster-rcnn-with-new-dataset).

I have done all the previous steps. But When I try to run the demo with `python ./tools/demo.py --gpu 0 --net vgg16` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./tools/demo.py", line 17, in
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg
File "/home/hadi/Software/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/config.py", line 23, in
from easydict import EasyDict as edict
ImportError: No module named easydict
```

I have installed easydict with both of these commands:

```
sudo pip install easydict
pip install easydict
```

Is this related to python path? I have installed both python 2.7 and 3.5. Since then I get all these python related errors. For example I have installed `tensorflow` for both python 2 and 3. But with python 2 it always says:

```
No module named tensorflow
```

How can I fix this?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what is the output of `which pip`?

Comment: By the way, do not send the same question at different network sites: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732185/importerror-no-module-named-easydict)

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. The output of `which pip` is : **/usr/local/bin/pip**. I think when I use `pip` or `pip3` the modules are installed in python 3 both times. They aren't installed in python 2.7.

Comment: What is the output of: `/usr/local/bin/pip --version` ?

Comment: Thus is the output: **pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)**. When I try to install easydict, the result of both 'pip install easydict` and `pip3 install easydict` is : **Requirement already satisfied: easydict in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages**

Comment: How did you install `pip` ?

Comment: I think I used this: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: I will add an answer, follow the instructions see if it works for you.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad Cross-posting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732185/importerror-no-module-named-easydict) on multiple exchanges is considered a no-no on the Stack Exchange.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad That is explained about [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it seems that you don't have `pip v2` so to make sure it's installed run:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

It will installs `pip` for `python v2`, now lets update it:

```
/usr/bin/pip2 install pip --upgrade --user
```

After updating, run `which pip2`; It should give you something like:

```
/home/your-user-name/.local/bin/pip2
```

Now use `pip2` to install your desired module for `python2`:

```
pip2 install easydict --user
```

or

```
/home/your-user-name/.local/bin/pip2 install easydict --user
```

*Do not forget to change `your-user-name` with your username*.