# On Ubuntu 16.04, pip is installing libraries to python 2.7

Tags: 16.04, python, libraries, pip

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to learn python. I use pyCharm IDE and python 3.5 but now when I'm trying to install libraries using the `sudo pip` command they are installing to python 2.7, so when I'm running my script I get

```
ImportError: No module named  ...
```

How should I install libraries via pip for Python 3?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I'm not a python person, but the default python is Ubuntu 16.04 is python 2.7.  To use python3 you type `python3`.  `pip` defaults to the default python (thus 2.7), and you use pip3 to use the 'pip' for python3  (pip3 is found in package `python3-pip`)

Comment: @guiverc thx man its working now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named easydict](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911026/importerror-no-module-named-easydict)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a python person, but the default `python` in Ubuntu 16.04 is python 2.7. To use python3 you type `python3`.

`pip` applies to the default python (thus 2.7), and you use `pip3` when you want to use the *'pip'* for python3 (pip3 being found in package `python3-pip`)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `pip3` for the python3 libraries.

Anything related to Python3 goes like this:

```
pip3 install library-name
```

if this gives you authentication error, add --user

```
pip3 install --user  app-name
```

If you want to upgrade the specific app/library

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade app-name
```